# Парсинг JSON из локального файла проекта

Tags: objective-c, json

Есть локальный файл внутри проекта, и мне надо из него спарсить конкретные данные - `cityName`, а у меня выходит парсить только весь файл (значение массива `cities`). Как из него достать значение `cityName`?

Вот код JSON файла

```
{"cities":[
    {"cityName":"Minsk", "countryCode":"BY", "cityDescription":"Minsk is the capital of Belarus"},
    {"cityName":"Moscow", "countryCode":"RUS", "cityDescription":"Moscow is the capital of Russia"},
    {"cityName":"Prague", "countryCode":"CZ", "cityDescription":"Prague is the capital of Czech Republic"},
    {"cityName":"Washington", "countryCode":"USA", "cityDescription":"Washington is the capital of United States of America"},
    {"cityName":"Stockholm", "countryCode":"SWN", "cityDescription":"Stockholm is the capital of Sweden"},
    {"cityName":"Beijing", "countryCode":"СHN", "cityDescription":"Beijing is the capital of China"},
    {"cityName":"Tokyo", "countryCode":"JPN", "cityDescription":"Tokyo is the capital of Japan"},
    {"cityName":"London", "countryCode":"UK", "cityDescription":"London is the capital of Great Britain"},
    {"cityName":"Madrid", "countryCode":"SPN", "cityDescription":"Madrid is the capital of Spain"},
    {"cityName":"Paris", "countryCode":"FR", "cityDescription":"Paris is the capital of France"}
]}
```

Вот код на Objective-С

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"citiesJSON" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *parsedJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray *cities  = [parsedJSON objectForKey:@"cities"];

NSLog(@"%@", cities);
```

Answer (score 1):

Из массива `cities` достать данные по ключу можно так:

```
for (NSDictionary* dict in cities) {
  NSString* cityName = dict[@"cityName"]
}
```